# Upload file for oracle OCI by c#

Tags: c#, oracle, amazon-s3, .net-core, upload

I searched how I can upload file to oracle OCI and I know its S3 compatible but I don't know what the SDK I can use? any example for upload file to oracle OCI by c# .net core 5.
I received info for oracle OCI from client like (storage_endpoint,storage_access_key_id,storage_secret_access_key ,region and bucket_name)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The SDK is documented here https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/API/SDKDocs/dotnetsdk.htm

Answer (score 0):

AWSSDK.S3 for C# is not compatible with Oracle.
The only supported clients SDK are Java, JavaScript, and Python.

Furthermore, you can't use `storage_endpoint`, `storage_access_key_id`, `storage_secret_access_key` with the OCI object storage client.

Answer (score -1):

I do not know this Oracle product but if it truly is S3 compatible I would suggest using the AWS SDK (`AWSSDK.S3` on NuGet).

There are many tutorials on how to use it, I don't think posting a guide here would be more helpful. If you encounter specific problems then please do ask further questions.